# Replace certain dates with NA in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, na

How can I replace the value/date 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in one columne with NA in R?

tried this:

```
ESM13$Committed[ESM13$Committed == "1970-01-01 00:00:00"] <- NA
```

didn't work. Couldn't figure out how to use mutate either.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear why that wouldn't work. There must be something going on with the data itself. Is the column imported as a POSIXct value? or a character value? or something else?

Comment: what if you do: `ESM13[ESM13$Committed == "1970-01-01 00:00:00",]$Committed <- NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `1970-01-01 00:00:00` is the datetime associated with the internal value of `0`. So I'm guessing the following should work:

```
ESM13$Committed[as.numeric(ESM13$Committed) == 0] <- NA
```